# Reading offsetHeight triggers layout and takes a long time

Tags: javascript, performance

I'm trying to improve my code performance. There's a line of code that takes more time than all of the other code combined. Take a look at the highlighted function below

[image: screenshot of performance tab]

It takes 125ms to read the offsetHeight. Here's the code that the performance tab highlights

```
const navBar = document.querySelector('.navigation.fixed');
if(navBar){
    const navBarHeight = navBar.offsetHeight,
        isRetracting = navBar.classList.contains('retracting');
    let scrollPos = window.scrollY;
...
```

I don't see what's so difficult about this that the browser is spending such a long time to read this height. Can someone explain to me what could be the reason for it?

Comment: It's not reading taking the time, it's layout recalculation. You should not read and write layout values in the same function.

Comment: I'm only reading the value. I never change the height of the `navBar`.

Comment: Most likely you're changing some other value then. Take a look at [this article](https://kellegous.com/j/2013/01/26/layout-performance/) it sheads some light on how the DOM works ([more](https://gist.github.com/paulirish/5d52fb081b3570c81e3a)). To avoid the recalculation issues, make a JS model of the actions, and update the model, and read the values from the model instead of reading them from the DOM.